# How to recover my /usr/lib/docker/graph/ directory?

Tags: linux, docker

My docker images gets stored in `/usr/lib/docker/graph`. I tried to delete all the images stored in `/usr/lib/docker/graph/*`. But unfortunately i deleted the graph directory itself. Now, i am unable to build a docker image. It says `/usr/lib/docker/graph no images`

Any solutions?

Comment: Re-install docker (now that you have lost your images) or restore a backup (you have a valid  backup I suppose)

Comment: I cannot able to uninstall docker. Any links? I tried `yum remove docker` notheing works

Comment: what happens when you do `yum remove docker` ? What error message do you get ? have you tried using `--force` ?

Comment: Ya I removed docker successfully. `yum remove docker-somenumbers.io` and now i run into [this issue](http://askubuntu.com/questions/580714/how-do-i-change-the-mount-point-of-a-file-system-is-it-safe) during installation. no space.